# Inverse of symmetric matrix that is almost diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, sparse-matrices

I have an $N\times N$ matrix $\mathbb X$ with entries:

$$X_{ij} = x_i\delta_{ij} + y_i(\delta_{i+m,j}+\delta_{i,j+m})$$

where $1 \le m \le N$, and $x_i,y_i$ are given numbers.

Is there an analytical formula for the inverse of $\mathbb X$? I've found numerically that $\mathbb X^{-1}$ is also sparse, with non-zeros on the main diagonal and a few other diagonals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your matrix $X$ is actually the result of the row and column permutation of a block diagonal matrix with $m$ tridiagonal blocks. You can permute the rows and columns such that the original rows/columns $$
1,1+m,1+2m,\ldots,1+\left\lfloor\frac{N-1}{m}\right\rfloor m,\\
2,2+m,2+2m,\ldots,2+\left\lfloor\frac{N-2}{m}\right\rfloor m,\\
\vdots \\
m,m+m,m+2m,\ldots,m+\left\lfloor\frac{N-m}{m}\right\rfloor m
$$
form the new rows/columns $1,\ldots,N.$ You will get some tridiagonal blocks of size $\left\lfloor\frac Nm\right\rfloor$ and some tridiagonal blocks of size $\left\lceil\frac Nm\right\rceil,$ which you can invert in isolation using the formula given in [this link about tridiagonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix). In the end, you only have to undo the permutations.

Comment: Thanks. A simplification such as this one was what brought me to editing https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3228824/10063.